# My plugin class doesn't work!

Tags: plugin-development, actions

Long story short; I'm writing a plugin in OOP. The constructor is run, but the callback of my add_action does not run. I just can't find out why.

I have added echo's on different spots to see what works and what not. The constructor is run, though the `pepare()` method is not.

`WP_DEBUG` is enabled, though I'm not getting any warnings or errors.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simplist slider
Description: My description
Version: 1.0
Author: Tim Severien
*/

class SimplistSlider {
    public function __construct() {
        // something is wrong here
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'prepare'));
    }

    public function prepare() {
        // registers
        wp_register_style('simplist-slider', plugins_url('/css/simplist-slider.css', __FILE__), array(), '1');
        wp_register_script('simplist-slider', plugins_url('/js/simplist-slider.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1');

        // enqueues
        wp_enqueue_style('simplist-slider');
        wp_enqueue_script('simplist-slider');

        add_shortcode('slider', array($this, 'shortcode'));
    }

    public function shortcode($attr, $content = NULL) {
        // format content, irrelevant
    }
}

$simplist_slider = new SimplistSlider();
?>
```

I'm running a fresh Wordpress 3.4.2 installation.

Thanks in advance.

---

**edit**

After modifying the code (you guys suggested), I have manage to get the shortcode working! Thanks!

Problem is, that my style and script isn't loaded. Have a look at my updated code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simplist slider
Description: My description
Version: 1.0
Author: Tim Severien
*/

class SimplistSlider {
    public function __construct() {
        // adding shortcode here
        add_shortcode('slider', array($this, 'shortcode'));

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'registerScripts'));
    }

    public function registerScripts() {
        // registers
        wp_register_style('simplist-slider', plugins_url('/css/simplist-slider.css', __FILE__), array(), '1');
        wp_register_script('simplist-slider', plugins_url('/js/simplist-slider.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1');

        // enqueues
        wp_enqueue_style('simplist-slider');
        wp_enqueue_script('simplist-slider');
    }

    public function shortcode($attr, $content = NULL) {
        // format content, irrelevant
    }
}

function simplist_slider_init() {
    $simplist_slider = new SimplistSlider();
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'simplist_slider_init');

?>
```

---

**edit #2**

- Please drop whatever your holding in your primary hand
- Look at the palm of your hand
- Continue moving your hand towards your head until they make contact

`facepalm();`

I screwed up the theme and removed the `wp_head();` function. My sincere apologies! Everything works as expected now.

Comment: My guess is that you are using the wrong action hook when adding the short code. Try with `init` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. That should work, though it might not be the best hook.

Comment: @hampusn It did fix my shortcode, but my script and style isn't loading now. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @hampusn Never mind. Your reply fixed the problem. If you post it as an actual answer I can select as answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Tim but you should mark @Vinicius's answer as the correct one. He bothered to find the correct hook :)

Comment: The `add_shortcode` function didn't work at the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. He only mentioned the hook for calling my class.

Comment: Your right. I posted an answer to your question. Please notify me if there is anything unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong hook to add your shortcode. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is executed way too late and should only be used to add javascript includes.

You should instead consider using the hook called `init` for adding your shortcodes. This hook is called after the current theme's `functions.php` has been included which means that you don't risk getting your shortcode overridden (unless that is a desired feature) by the theme if there is a name collision.

Here is a list of available actions: [Plugin API - Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

If you're going with the `init` hook for the shortcodes but still want the plugin to be hooked to `plugins_loaded` you could do something like these changes:

```
class SimplistSlider {
    public function __construct() {
        // Hook shortcodes
        add_action('init', array($this, 'registerShortcodes'));
        // Hook javascripts
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'registerScripts'));
    }

    // ...

    public function registerShortcodes() {
        // adding shortcodes here
        add_shortcode('slider', array($this, 'shortcode'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way for including plugins is using the `plugins_loaded` hook.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'simplist_slider_init' );
function simplist_slider_init() {
    $simplist_slider = new SimplistSlider();
}
```

Apart from that, if you're correctly enabling the plugin in the admin interface, you should be able to echo things in the function above and so on.

Comment: I have added some additional information. Please have a look at that.